# How do you hide multiple views at once?

Tags: android, layout, sdk, visibility

I have a `RelativeLayout` view, and 3 children's views too.  I'm trying to hide them all in code by setting the relative layout to INVISIBLE using `setVisibility`.  The funny thing is that when I use `setVisibility(View.INIVISIBLE)` only the first child is hidden, not the other two.  So I'm a bit confused - if I set a parent view to invisible shouldn't it change the visibility of all the children or leave them all alone?

Feel free to point me to a reference page that explains it - I can't find anything.

Update:  I've tried setting it to `View.GONE`, but the same thing happens, except the two children who remain visible move up a bit.

Here's the relevant XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/optionsform"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvoptions"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/tvoptions"
        android:textColor="#f000"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:textStyle="bold"/>
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvdictionary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvoptions"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/dictionary"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:textColor="#f000" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/dictionary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tvdictionary"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvdictionary" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here's the relevant code I'm using:

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Toggle viewing of options, using "if" in case it is set to View.GONE 
        View view = findViewById(R.id.optionsform);
        if (view.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) 
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        else
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Comment: Please post your layout and code. The way you described it is correct, hiding the layout hides all the children under normal circumstances.

Comment: This is really strange, I wonder if it's something to do with relative layout.. Can you try temporarily changing it to linearlayout and see if the same issue happens

Comment: could you please paste your whole activity code here..

Comment: Solved.  An uninstall then install of the app on my android device did the trick.  I'll beware of that in future.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Solved.  An uninstall then install of the app on my android device did the trick. I'll beware of that in future

Comment: Comment if you downvote.  This was the solution for me.

Answer (score 3):

Try to set all three views to `View.INVISIBLE` or to `View.GONE`.

OR

You can try

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    //Toggle viewing of options, using "if" in case it is set to View.GONE 
    RelativeLayout view = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.optionsform);
    if (view.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) 
        view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    else
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: Well yes I could do that, but its a lot of redundant code if it doing it to the parent should be enough.  I shall look into it on Monday again using the suggestions above.

Answer (score 2):

You must set to the `View.GONE` state.

Comment: he might just want to hide (invisible) it...   but worth to try

Comment: Gone doesn't seem to help - it just moves the two children that remain visible a bit further up the screen.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvdictionary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        **android:layout_below="@+id/tvoptions"** // *should  be  android:layout_below="@id/tvoptions*
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/dictionary"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:textColor="#f000" />



     <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/dictionary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            **android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tvdictionary"** // *should be android:layout_alignTop="@id/tvdictionary*
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvdictionary"// *should be android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tvdictionary*
 />
```

**@id is used while referencing layout id

@+id is used while creating new layout id**

Comment: Interesting, the above is autogenerated code from the eclipse ADT plugin. I'll give that a go and get back to you.

Comment: I've looked into this and the "+" doesn't really make much of a difference - it is more for the tools to check that you're not introducing typos but doesn't affect the output.